# increase the sensitivity of the microphone

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm writing an app for Voice Call on Xamarin.Forms. Now faced with the problem that on Android the speaker can be heard on the speakerphone only when he brings the microphone to his mouth almost close, and in this position is very uncomfortable to show the video from the camera. How can you increase the sensitivity of the microphone software at the time of the call? Alternatively, how can you amplify the sound on the other side, if it is already at the maximum?

Comment: How do you record the audio?